# Dell Inspiron mini 1018 - Lubuntu Installation please

Tags: boot, lubuntu, dell

I'm new to linux, and have a [Dell Inspiron Mini 10v 1018](https://downloads.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_laptop/esuprt_inspiron_laptop/inspiron-mini1018_service%20manual_en-us.pdf) I want to use.

Since Monday I've tried to run Lubuntu but without success because after 1st installation it freezes on boot. I tried 18.04 and 16.04.

After I installed 15.05 and no problem on boot but can't use YouTube anymore, because Firefox is outdated. So i want to install a version that views YouTube and doesn't freezes on boot for this computer. Can any one help.

Comment: Have you tried the latest release, 20.04?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the 1 GB of RAM in the Inspiron Mini 10v 1018 is not adequate to install Lubuntu? It's hard to day, since [Lubuntu no longer provides minimum system requirements](https://lubuntu.me/taking-a-new-direction/).

However, you can try the latest version with a download of Lubuntu's 20.04 ISO file at http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/20.04/release/lubuntu-20.04-desktop-amd64.iso

Next, check for download errors by https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu

Make a LiveUSB following these instructions on [another Linux PC](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu)  on [a Windows PC](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)  or [on a MacOS X](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-macos) machine.

Once you make a LiveUSB, install it following these steps https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop

Answer (score 0):

I think i have found the solution from a post in this forum

i follwed the sets above and it solved the problem.

Edit the kernel boot parameters, using (whichever text editor, I just used pico)

sudo pico /etc/default/grub
and where it says GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"

add in systemd.restore_state=0 so it should read like:

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash systemd.restore_state=0"

thanks a lot